# Unit testing external service

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I want to unit test a function that consumes an external dependency.

here is the method:

```
public string GetUrl(string records = "")
{
    if (records.IsNullOrEmpty())
    {
        records = Partner.Current["Records"];
    }

    return string.Format(
        "http://{0}/{1}?pid={2}",
        recordsdomain,
        HttpUtility.UrlEncode(FullName
            .Replace(' ', '_')
            .Replace("\\", string.Empty)
            .Replace("?", string.Empty)),
        Id);
}
```

this method is sitting inside a class which has a constructor as follows:

```
public Person(Person person)
{
      FullName = person.firstname + person.lastname
}
```

the problem is:
Person does not have a public constructor, thats why it doesnt allow creating a mock for it.

Here is how person object is generated:

```
Person person = Service.GetPerson(Guid.Empty, "115763963", 1);
```

How to solve this?

**UPDATE**

The external service creates the person object and feeds the object off of its database. Also the object is declared on the external service so I cannot just create a new instance of it and feed the information into it.

Comment: Why can't you mock the service?

Comment: because the external service creates the object and feeds the object off of its database. Also the object is declared on the external service so I cannot just create a new instance of it and feed the information into it. does it make sense?

Comment: this sounds like a perfect example of when to use mocking in fact, mock the service and mock the method calls on it to return a Person for you. (in fact see @fan711's) answer below.

Comment: person has a private constructor. It doesn't let me mock it. here is the error: "argument type moq.Mock<person> is not assignable to parameter type <person>"

Comment: if your external service is under test and Service.GetPerson is already tested, you should only mock the service

Comment: @user3311522 Ah ok I see, you didn't mention that it had a private constructor

Comment: maybe if Person implement an IPerson...

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the mocking technique. You'd create a mock person object which return fixed values on firstname and lastname properties. You can then pass the mock person to the constructor.

Depending on which mock framework you choose the code would look different. Using Moq it would look something like:

```
var person = new Mock<Person>(); 
person.SetupGet(p => p.firstname).Returns("Joe");
person.SetupGet(p => p.firstname).Returns("Smith");
// your mock person does now return names for testing
// and you can pass it to the constructor
```

Comment: I've just noticed you're saying you can't moq it. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

**If** the external service functionality can be taken for granted, you could always fake it (bit of a burden but **if** you only need the data to test other code it might be viable).

```
Person person = Service.GetPerson(Guid.Empty, "115763963", 1);
```

would become

```
Person person = FakeService.GetPerson(Guid.Empty, "115763963", 1);
```

where you'd have something like

```
public static class FakeService
{
    public static Person GetPerson(Guid foo, string bar, int baz)
    {
        Person something = new Person{ /*Put nice data here*/ };
        return something;
    }
}
```

Maybe rough, but should get you going *if you only need the service to provide you some data to work with, that is. If you also need to test the service itself, this approach would obviously be nonsensical*.

UPDATE: Since `Person`'s ctor is inaccessible, for this approach to work you're going to have to fake that too... One thing to immediately check is, if `Person` is a `partial` class you might be able to pull it off adding simply a new ctor to it (needs to be tried, been a while since i did something like this):

```
public partial class Person
{
    public Person(){}
}
```

I use this approach to expand auto-generated data context classes, it might work for you too.

On a less serious note, you could also ask for a public ctor overload to be added to that class!

Comment: I thinks this solution is very close to the optimum answer. here is the error though: 

Person something = new Person { /*Put nice data here*/ }; ***Cannot access protected constructor "person" here

Comment: I get it. You *might* have to fake Person too, then... I'll update the answer.

Comment: Ignore it. it is "Person"

Comment: Unfortunately person is abstract. Couldn't do that approach...either :(